# Site not rendering on some IOS devices [White screen of death?]

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, angular-material2

### Current behavior

My application which I have built and uploaded to https://callum.tech/new will not render on some IOS devices, I havnt tested this on a huge array but I have tested it on 2 devices, my personal iPhone 5 running IOS 10.3.3 and my friends iPad which I cannot recall the version.
It will simply render a white page, no matter how many refreshes, or going into 'private' etc it refuses to render.
To eliminate the potential for this being just my phone (when I first discovered the issue) I fully formatted it to factory settings and still same result, tried on multiple locations (aka varying IPs), tried VPN, wifi to mobile etc.

Here is it running on http://browserstack.com and return a white page with no real errors: (I am also out of free sessions so that is currently out of the question
[image]

### Expected behavior

Pages renders like it does in some IOS devices and andriod

### Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions

Here is my full up to date github of the project: https://github.com/kenji-1996/CallumTech
I am not sure how it can be fully tested, but I cannot even debug the potential console errors because I do not own a mac to use Safari 6 web inspector feature

### What is the motivation / use case for changing the behavior?

I want my site to actually run

### Note

I have had older versions working fine on my phone, i am not sure what point it started breaking

### Environment

```
Angular version:  4.4.6, is this the latest?


Browser:
- [x ] Chrome (iOS) version 'CriOS/62/0/3203/70 Mobile/14G60 Safari/602.1
- [x ] Safari (iOS) version 602.1
 
For Tooling issues:
- Node version: v8.4.0
- Platform:  IOS

Others:
- Build using this: ng build --prod --base-href /new/ --build-optimizer
```

Comment: ok what is your app base ? the target is it es5 or es6?

Comment: @FatehMohamed tsconfig.json says `"target": "es5",` which i assume refers to using es5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is including `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` here:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-navbar',
    templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Comment: I'm using ViewEncapsulation.None and run into the same issue

Comment: For all components or only in the root-component?